# how to loop element for list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

list=[[`AA`,'1'] ,[`BB`,'4'] ,['CC','3']]

I want expand list[0] of count list[1]

Expected output: ['AA','BB','BB','BB','BB','CC','CC','CC']

I try below 2 ways but not works... Please could tell me where i need to fix?

```
⓵
variableName = []
         for row in rows:
            vName = row[0]
            count = int(row[1])
                          
            result = Counter(vName=count)
            variableName.append(list(result.elements()))

⓶
variableName = []
         for row in rows:
            vName = row[0]
            count = int(row[1])
　　　　　　while count < countRW:
                variableName.append(vName)
```

Comment: You are making it harder than it should be. Try simplifying like: `[i for i, n in list1 for _ in range(int(n))]`?

Comment: First time i try python thats why i don`t know some keyword.. Thanks for your answer i will try that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach would work if you construct the `Counter` object properly by passing a dict object instead of a keyword argument with a fixed name, and if you call `list.extend` instead to avoid nesting the list:

```
for row in rows:
    vName = row[0]
    count = int(row[1])
    result = Counter({vName: count})
    variableName.extend(list(result.elements()))
```

Your second approach would work if you keep decreasing the counter in the `while` loop and exit the loop when the counter reaches 0:

```
for row in rows:
    vName = row[0]
    count = int(row[1])
    while count > 0:
        variableName.append(vName)
        count -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the list you have given isn't in correct format. It should be like`list1 =[['AA','1'] ,['BB','4'] ,['CC','3']]`

After that you can use the output function and pass your desired list as an argument you will get an list in return :

```
list1 =[['AA','1'] ,['BB','4'] ,['CC','3']]

def output(rows):
    variableName = []
    for row in rows:
        vName = row[0]
        count = int(row[1])
        for num_of_element in range(count):
            variableName.append(vName)
    return variableName

print(output(list1))
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. when i use that i get error "TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".

Comment: I have edited the answer. This time you shouldn't get any Error. Try to understand the code.